# How can we estimate the likelihood field for a particular scan in probabilistic terms?

Tags: slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[image: image description]
I am trying to implement a scan matcher using Scan based sensor model but I cant figure out how to estimate likelihood for a particular scan. Is there any implementation available ? Would be thankful for help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270460/how-can-we-estimate-the-likelihood-field-for-a-particular-scan-in-probabilistic-terms-?/) by [ZainMehdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28126/zainmehdi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 225 on 2017-09-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-08**:
Can you please clarify how this is related to ROS? With over 35000 questions, we try to stay on-topic as much as possible.

For more general robotics related questions, I'd refer you to `robotics.stackexchange.com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If anyone is looking for the answer. ROS amcl package contains this implementation as described in the book (Probabilistic Robotics)
http://wiki.ros.org/amcl

---

Originally posted by [ZainMehdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28126/zainmehdi/) with karma: 225 on 2017-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0